# Drawing Gui on different resolutions with viewport - libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am using FillViewport ( A FillViewport keeps the aspect ratio of the virtual screen size, it will always fill the whole screen which might result in parts of the viewport being cut off!)
I am trying to make my game run on multiple resolutions, when it comes to scaling world I am just using FillViewport and it works just like intended.
But when it comes to  GUI, I dont know how to draw it so its always withing the screen borders ( parts of screen bein cutted off is the part of the problem here, lets say my x value for something is 0, if 0-15px is cutted of I wont see 15 pixels of my sprite)

How should I go around fixing this problem?

Comment: You can have multiple viewports at the same time. You could for example create another viewport (for example a StretchViewport) for the UI, while the rest uses the other viewport

Comment: donfuxx is right, however you will need to be more careful in case you are using different viewports. You can only use them one by one. Use `viewport1.apply()`, then draw your world, then do `viewport2.apply()` and draw your UI. You won't be able to use them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I literally worked months on my GUI code and never got it right until I found this very important detail @noone mentioned...